# What's the best way to structure code to allow a constructor to be updated by multiple developers

Tags: c#

We have multiple developers all updating one class which has a constructor as below.

```
public class A
{
    private readonly IB<W, X> _property1;
    private readonly IB<Y, Z> _property2;

    public MyClass(IC c)
        : this(
            new IB<W, X>(),
            new IB<Y, Z>(c)
        )
    {
    }

    public MyClass(
        IB<W, X> property1,
        IB<Y, Z> property2
    )
    {
        _property1 = property1;
        _property2 = property2;
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to allow developers to add new parameters to the constructors without editing any existing files, so that we can use T4 templates to generate alterations, something like below although this currently isn't allowed in C# as far as I know.

```
public partial class A
{
    private readonly IB<U, V> _property3;

    public partial MyClass(IC c)
        : this(
           new IB<U, V>()                
        )
    {
    }

    public partial MyClass(
        IB<U, V> property3
        )
    {
        _property3 = property3;
    }
}
```

This code is pretty generic and most of the time it will be the same, we are using T4 templates to generate some of it, but we have to manually copy the generated code into the class. What I would like to do is be able to maybe have multiple partial classes of MyClass (or something else) so that we can always generate the code and then manually update one file where necessary. The problem is that I can't think of a way to structure the code to allow this, can anyone think of a way that I could achieve this?

Edit 1: updated to try to make the question clearer

Comment: What do you mean but structuring the code? what have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

I would think that's what `partial` is for.

> It is possible to split the definition of a class or a struct, an
>   interface or a method over two or more source files. Each source file
>   contains a section of the type or method definition, and all parts are
>   combined when the application is compiled.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

```
public partial class MyClass
{
    public void MyClass()
    {
    }
}

public partial class MyClass
{
    public void MyClass(Foo bar)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Partial classes can work, but perhaps this would be better suited to using a DI container

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using sub versioning. For example: TortoiseSVN (http://tortoisesvn.net/about.html.)

SVN manages merging the code changes from multiple developers. When you are working on a critical section in the code, you can lock the file, temporary preventing other programmers from committing their code changes.